# How to handle timezone when loading a CSV file with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently facing a problem when loading data via the read_csv() function of pandas.

Here is an extract of a record from the CSV file :

2021-11-28T03:13:01+00:00,49.59,49.93,49.56,49.88

When I use pandas to_csv() my index column which is in timestamp systematically loses one hour on all records

The previous example look like this after using pandas :

2021-11-28T0**2**:13:01+00:00,49.59,49.93,49.56,49.88

Here is python snippet code. :

```
df_mre_unpacked = pd.read_csv('mre_unpacked.csv', sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index_col='timestamp',decimal=".")

df_mre_unpacked = df_mre_unpacked[['ASG1.CPU10_XV_ACHSE1_ZR','ASG1.CPU11_XV_ACHSE2_ZR','ASG2.CPU10_XV_ACHSE1_ZR','ASG2.CPU11_XV_ACHSE2_ZR']]
```

Here is the original CSV [image: CSV view from Excel]

Result of pandas dataframe head() function :

[image: Screenshot from jupyter lab]

As you can see the first records start from 03:13:01 from the CSV file but from the panda dataframe it begains with 02:13:01 since I do not have this timestamp in my csv file

Has anyone had this problem before ?

**UPDATE :**

I have a better view of the problem now. Here is what I discovered.

When I do the data extraction via a portal the time that is displayed is as follows:

[image]

Here is the same record read from the CSV file with notepad++

[image]

The problem comes from the extraction process that automatically removes one hour.

How do I add 1 hour to my timestamp column which is my index?

Comment: Timezones perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime.timestamp() loses an time (an hour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296599/datetime-timestamp-loses-an-time-an-hour)

Comment: Yes it is the same problem I am on the time zone of Paris. I don't know what I have to change in my code to solve this problem.

Comment: You cant figure it out from the answered question that is posted here? Even tho in your own words its the same problem?

Comment: For the moment I have not solved the problem I am working on it to solve it. I will write the answer to the problem once the solution is found. 

For the stackoverflow link you shared it's exactly the same problem with the difference that my timestamp is not built on an Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to simply add this snippet code :

```
df_de18_EventData.index = pd.to_datetime(df_de18_EventData.index) + pd.Timedelta("1 hour")
```

This will add 1 hour to the index timestamp column

It's not the best solution but it works for now. An optimal solution would be to take into account automatically the time difference like excel does

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it doesn't exactly answer OPs question