# Get the local time without daylight savings applied, using the latest methodology

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am trying to get the local time without the application of daylight savings time.

I know that I can get the local time with the following, but when my location is in DST I get an extra hour. I want standard time all the time.

`localTime = datetime.now()`

My searches have found a lot of references to the pytz module. But there are references to using builtin functions and not to use pytz as of version 3.6 of python as it is deprecated.

What I am after is the correct way of doing this in version 3.11 of python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime.timestamp() loses an time (an hour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296599/datetime-timestamp-loses-an-time-an-hour)

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken sorry it does not, or I can't see how it would.

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken That question is about timezones, not DST.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Barmar . There are details on this behaviour explained in https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handling-timezone-and-dst-changes-with-python#generating-the-correct-schedule-time . I have since retracted my vote to close as duplicate..

Comment: Out of interest, what’s the use case? If at a certain time of year a location uses DST, then that’s the time at that location at that time of year. What do you want to do with a time that’s *not* the actual time at that location?

Comment: @deceze I think it's the issue in the site in the above link. Scheduling recurring events at the same time, which should not shift when DST changes.

Comment: @Barmer “Same time” meaning e.g. “9am”, regardless of DST or not? Then there are better ways to approach that IMO, namely by storing “9am” and building a complete timestamp from that for recurrences.

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken, the hacksoft link you gave deals with scheduling not getting the current system time, so is not a suitable answer. It is also trying to generate a time that is the same hour (3pm) irrespective of DST state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```py
import datetime as dt
import time

# Dynamically fetch local standard time and build a fixed timezone.
# time.timezone is the local time's number of seconds WEST of prime meridian (- for east).
LST = dt.timezone(-dt.timedelta(seconds=time.timezone), 'LST')
print(dt.datetime.now(tz=LST))  # I am in PST now (GMT-8)
print()

# Normally PST daylight time would be -07:00 April - November.
for month in range(1, 13):
    print(dt.datetime(2024, month, 1, tzinfo=LST))
```

Output:

```
2024-01-18 16:11:12.090088-08:00

2024-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-02-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-03-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-04-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-05-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-06-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-07-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-08-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-09-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-10-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-11-01 00:00:00-08:00
2024-12-01 00:00:00-08:00
```